# Add Widgets from files automatically in pyQT

Tags: design-patterns, plugins, pyqt

I would like to add widgets to my QT application App.py more or less dynamically by serving the widgets through a folder structure like so

```
App.py
plugins
-> plugin_A
   -> main.py
- plugins_B
   -> main.py
```

Every main.py is representing a QT widget which is then shown in the main application.

```
+-------------------+
| PLUGIN A          |
| [Button]          |
| [Label]           |
+-------------------+
| PLUGIN B          |
| [Checkbox 1]      |
| [Checkbox 2]      |
| [Button]          |
+-------------------+
| ...               |
```

I thought about simply scanning the plugins folder, creating and saving the Widgets in a list and adding them to a layout in a loop.

**Upside** I could easily propagate down common functionality to the constructor, like a COM port or something like that.

**Downside** The approach feels naiv and it would feel much better if the Widgets would register themselves actively somehow, but I don't know if and why this way is maybe preferable.

The whole situation seems to be so common, that I wonder if there is a general pattern to start with, maybe QT already has some functionality for such cases?

Comment: While it could be a common requirement, its implementation is completely case-dependent: there is no general pattern, only you can know what best fits your needs. Note that this makes your question opinion based (and, as such, off-topic).

Comment: @musicamante opinion based is harsh, since an answer covering some of the patterns usually used for such cases would be perfectly unbiased and helpful as a starting point. Also the other question is if qt has some functionality or not, which is a simple yes or no question

Comment: It is opinion based in the sense that there are uncountable ways of doing this, depending on the needs. The "plugins" might be self-contained and not require actual interaction with the main application, or they might need bidirectional communication (which would require some sort of "API" system). Qt doesn't directly provide such a thing, as that's not its scope (that's up to the programmer), you can only dynamically load "unknown" UI files by crawling the paths, but they would provide very limited interaction (only direct signal/slot connections).

Comment: It is *feasible*, for example by using basic ui files that are completely based on promoted widgets (which would then automatically import their promoted classes), and then using the QMetaObject features you could access properties, signals and slots. That would be quite difficult, and probably unnecessarily complex: at that point, you'd just implement your own plugin system, which would be more flexible according to your needs. Which brings us again to the first point: the very concept of "plugin system" is too abstract and broad, and there are virtually infinite ways of implementing it.